# create esxi server in docker image

Tags: docker, vmware, esxi

I would like to create a vmware image based on an linux ISO file. The whole thing should take place within a build pipeline - using docker images.

My approach is that I look for a suitable docker image with an free esxi server and use this as the basis in the build pipeline. Unfortunately I can not find an image on dockerhub. 
Isn't this approach possible?

I would have expected that several people would have done this before me and that I could use an existing docker image accordingly.

Comment: Esxi might be free to use under certain conditions, but it is not open source. Realistically, probably only VMWare  or a partner would be able to to distribute such an image.

Comment: This means the way to go is to use a free esxi server on a computer instead of a  docker image...

Comment: There is this project: https://github.com/andyneff/docker-esxi  , it relies on building an image from your own esxi  ISO.  And it doesn't claim the final image actually boots.